# Play localization default + 50 languages

Tags: google-play

My application doesn't support localization , it support only usEnglish. Whenever i opened the apk details it shows **Localizations:default + 50 languages**. Why it is showing like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Android library projects that included other languages (eg. strings.xml in values-fr), then Google Play would detect the partial translation for other languages and take it as a supported language.  The only way to correct this is probably to remove strings from language-specific values directories from all the Android lib projects your project uses.